# Add homepage to the list of pages in the Footer Widget

Tags: pages, widgets, footer, list

How do you add the homepage to the list of pages appearing in the footer widget?
I've spent a few hours looking around for a function adding the list of pages in the footer widget but I can't seem to find one and I haven't found a way to do this via wordpress customizer

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating a custom menu from the customizer, then adding a widget to the footer containing said menu. Much easier than I thought it was going to be